# Create non English directories in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to be able to create folders for the registered  users under their names. Their info is stored in my db in Cyrillic characters and pulled from their when creating the folder. The thing is if the info is in English everything is ok, if in Cyrillic I get something like РљСѓР»СЊС‡РјР°РЅРѕРІР°. Everything is set to utf-8. If I set folder name to i.e 'фыва'  it creates it no problem.

```
        $this->load->model('users_model');
    $i=$this->session->userdata('uid');
    $new_name=$this->input->post('doc_name');
    $folder=$this->users_model->getFullName($i); //$folder='фыва' works fine

    if(!is_dir("./uploads/".$folder)){
        mkdir("./uploads/".$folder , 0777);
    }
    $config['file_name'] = $new_name;
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/'.$folder.'/';
```

Will appreciate any help

Comment: I really urge you to use the uid instead of some utf-8 string for the folder names.

Comment: Does the CodeIgniter Database module handle different collations in MySQL?  Multibyte stuff is not automatic in PHP, if it doesn't handle it properly, it'll do stuff like that.

Comment: On which platform are you? Windows filename conventions can be bizarre, and there's no standard encoding on any platform anyways.

Answer (score 3):

I *strongly* recommend you to use *only* plain ASCII characters in directory names on servers, or even better: only numbers, lowercase letters, and underscore.  Using special characters quite always brings trouble, and seems like you are already having some.

I suggest you to name the directory as the numeric user ID (they surely have one), padding with zeroes if you find it looks better (all the names have equal length).

Comment: ok I will go with user ids... but what about the document name?  The user will upload the document and name it in the form, therefore in his/her folder I want to see the name of the doc after saving. (in Cyrillic). if i set the name manually it works, but not when pulled from the form

Comment: You can store the file names in the DB as well, in a table with essentially three columns (userid, fileid, filename) so that you can recall the actual name from the database, and instead get the file data from the filesystem. I understand it looks weird, but it's how things are done actually. Think about it: what happens if the user uploads a file with a name which is longer than the maximum allowed by your server file system? Or with a name that contains '..' so that if you concatenate it with some path, it can back-navigate your directory structure? Too much stuff to check.

Comment: More, if the files are small enough (few KBs) you can store them in BLOBs. Be careful however, this can sink your DB if abused.

Comment: Another advantage of putting the file names as entries in the DB, is that you can easily 1) list the files belonging to an user; 2) count them; 3) rename them; 4) manage naming collisions effectively and easily just using a UNIQUE key on two columns (userid, filename). Think 'bout it.

Comment: Sorry guys the last sentence of a comment of mine, telling about the ".." issue in filenames, is plain bullshit. The rest is good.